# Notificações repetindo todos os dias

Tags: android, android-studio, android-notification, notificação

Estou tentando fazer um app que chegue notificações em horários determinados pelo usuário todos os dias, porém só consegui fazer que elas chegassem uma vez.

Esse é o código que tenho até agora:

```
private void salvar() {    
    RespostasAguaCasa p = new RespostasAguaCasa();

    p.setId(1);
    p.setValoragua(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.valoragua);
    p.setAcordarhora(EscolhaAguaCasa.hourx);
    p.setAcordarminu(EscolhaAguaCasa.minutex);
    p.setDormirhora(SegundaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxx);
    p.setDormirminu(SegundaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexx);
    p.setTerceirahora(TerceiraperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxx);
    p.setTerceiraminu(TerceiraperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxx);
    p.setQuartahora(QuartaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxxx);
    p.setQuartaminu(QuartaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxxx);
    p.setQuintahora(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxxxx);
    p.setQuintaminu(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxxxx);   

    Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
    calSet.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY , EscolhaAguaCasa.hourx);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, EscolhaAguaCasa.minutex);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    setAlarm(calSet);

}
```

Alarme:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(arg0)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.casa)
                .setContentTitle("ads")
                .setContentText("sad")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                ;

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

    }
}
```

`setAlarm` está na mesma classe que o `salvar`:

```
public void setAlarm(Calendar targetCall)
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm is set at" + targetCall.getTime(),
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getBaseContext(), 1, intent, 0);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCall.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trabalhando da forma como você está trabalhando, o jeito mais fácil de se fazer seria gerando a nova notificação quando a notificação for disparada, mais ou menos assim:

```
private void salvar() {    
    RespostasAguaCasa p = new RespostasAguaCasa();

    p.setId(1);
    p.setValoragua(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.valoragua);
    p.setAcordarhora(EscolhaAguaCasa.hourx);
    p.setAcordarminu(EscolhaAguaCasa.minutex);
    p.setDormirhora(SegundaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxx);
    p.setDormirminu(SegundaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexx);
    p.setTerceirahora(TerceiraperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxx);
    p.setTerceiraminu(TerceiraperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxx);
    p.setQuartahora(QuartaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxxx);
    p.setQuartaminu(QuartaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxxx);
    p.setQuintahora(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.hourxxxxx);
    p.setQuintaminu(QuintaperguntaAguaCasa.minutexxxxx);
    Notificacao.GerarNotificacao(this, System.currentTimeMillis(), EscolhaAguaCasa.hourx, EscolhaAguaCasa.minutex);
}

public static class Notificacao {
    public static void GerarNotificacao(Context ctx, int dataInMillis, int hora, int minuto) {
        Calendar calNow = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar calSet = (Calendar) calNow.clone();
        calSet.setTimeInMillis(dataInMillis);
        calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hora);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuto);
        calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        calSet.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        setAlarm(ctx, calSet);
    }

    private static void setAlarm(Context ctx, Calendar targetCall)
    {
        Toast.makeText(ctx, "Alarm is set at" + targetCall.getTime(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx, AlarmReceiver.class);

        PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(ctx, 1, intent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)ctx.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCall.getTimeInMillis(), pendingintent);
    }
}

public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(arg0)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.casa)
                .setContentTitle("ads")
                .setContentText("sad")
                .setAutoCancel(true);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());

        Calendar calHoje = Calendar.getInstance();
        calHoje.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
        calHoje.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

        Notificacao.GerarNotificacao(arg0, calHoje.getTimeInMillis(), EscolhaAguaCasa.hourx, EscolhaAguaCasa.minutex);
    }
}
```

Note que eu criei uma classe estática para gerar a notificação, mais fica a seu critério a implementação. Da forma como fiz, quando o sistema notificar o usuário ele automaticamente cria um novo alarme para um dia depois.

Comment: ele esta pedindo um setter na seguinte linha  ou pede para tornalo statico e vira um loopy de erro setAlarm(calSet); oque faço ?

Comment: acho que nao coloquei a minha classe set alarm vou colocar ela no post

Comment: @aleanderrayson Provavelmente este setAlarm está no seu código original.

Comment: Acho que nao estava tinha editado ele .

Comment: @aleanderrayson, inclui o método na classe de notificação

Comment: Tinha tentado isso ontem porem agora ela esta com outro erro criei outra pergunta sobre se puder dar uma olhada .Obrigada !https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/313306/como-usar-o-getsystemservice-n%C3%A3o-est%C3%A1tico

Comment: @aleanderrayson, respondi lá, se der certo marque as respostas como válidas

Comment: deu certinho obrigado